# Using global options in Symfony Console

Tags: php, symfony

I'm writing a console application, and need to allow the user to toggle between different environments.

```
<?php
$console = new Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
$console->setDispatcher($dispatcher);

$console->getDefinition()->addOptions([
    new InputOption(
        '--env',
        '-e',
        InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL,
        'The environment to operate in.',
        'DEV'
    )
]);

$dispatcher->addListener(ConsoleEvents::COMMAND, function (ConsoleCommandEvent $event) {
    // get the input instance
    $input = $event->getInput();

    print_R($event->getInput()->getOption('env'));exit;
});

$console->run();
```

When running the command (`cmdname --env=test`), I would expect to see `test`. However, I get an error saying that `The "env" option does not exist.`.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a small "var_dump testcase". Never got in touch with symfony/console before but it seems like options or arguments are not parsed through the inputinterface inside of a ConsoleCommandEvent.

Using your code with a "regular" command and not inside of a listener your env ist set properly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\ConsoleEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleCommandEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

$console = new Application();

$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
$console->setDispatcher($dispatcher);

$console->getDefinition()->addOptions([
    new InputOption(
        '--env',
        '-e',
        InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL,
        'The environment to operate in.',
        'DEV'
    )
]);

$console
    ->register('envtest')
    ->setCode(function (InputInterface $input,OutputInterface $output) {
//      $output->writeln('What is my env?')
        var_dump($input->getOptions());
    });

$dispatcher->addListener(ConsoleEvents::COMMAND, function (ConsoleCommandEvent $event) {

    $command = $event->getCommand();
    $application = $command->getApplication();

    //Check if your option is registerd within the console application
    var_dump($application->getDefinition()->getOptions());

    $input = $event->getInput();
    var_dump($input->getOptions());

    // get the input instance
    //var_dump($event->getInput()->getOptions());

});


$console->run();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the `InputOption` class constructor doesn't need the dashes :

```
$console->getDefinition()->addOptions([
    new InputOption(
        'env',
        'e',
        InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL,
        'The environment to operate in.',
        'DEV'
    )
]);
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/console_arguments.html